# Building a Map[String,String]

Tags: xml, scala

I have the following function. It works fine for printing the values i'm looking to store. I would like to build a Map[String, String]

```
def storePlayerEntry(n: Node, moved: Boolean) = {

    moved match {
      // storing a current player record
      // rowkey = playerid
      case true => {
        //println("current: " + teamId + ":" + n)
        println("id: " + n \ "@uID")
        for (
          s <- Seq("first_name",
            "last_name",
            "known_name",
            "birth_date",
            "weight",
            "height",
            "jersey_num",
            "real_position",
            "real_position_side",
            "join_date",
            "country")
        ) {
          val stat = (n \\ "Stat").filter(_.attribute("Type").filter(_.toString() == s).isDefined)
          Option(stat.text) match {
            case Some(st) if (st == "") => // do nothing
            case Some(st) => println(st)
            case None => // do nothing
          }
        }
        //val ret = dataApi.upsertMulti("players", 
      }
      case false => {
        //println("old: " + teamId + ":" + n)            
      }
    }
  }
```

I am avoiding declaring a map then just adding methods as I'm sure there is something more scala-ish to be done here.

The Map I'm looking for would containing something like s -> st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jdevelop is close.  Should be this:

```
val x = (for (
              s <- Seq("first_name",
                "last_name",
                "known_name",
                "birth_date",
                "weight",
                "height",
                "jersey_num",
                "real_position",
                "real_position_side",
                "join_date",
                "country");
              val st = (n \\ "Stat").filter(_.attribute("Type").filter(_.toString() == s).isDefined).text if (st != "")
            ) yield (s -> st)).toMap
```

Comment: awesome... thanks @chiappone. i can't vote it up... my rep is too low :(

Comment: went w/ a blend of this one and Travis'.
    
`var x = (for (s <- playerKeys;
              val st = (n \\ "Stat").filter(
_.attribute("Type").filter(_.toString() == s).isDefined).text 
if (st != "" && st != "Unknown")) yield (s -> st)).toMap`

Comment: @kyleroche: Note that that approach is going to have worse performance characteristics than mine, since you're searching through the sequence of nodes (not to mention creating the `NodeSeq`) for each key.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more idiomatic approach: First we make a set of all the keys we care about:

```
val keys = Set(
 "first_name",
 "last_name",
 "known_name",
 "birth_date",
 "weight",
 "height",
 "jersey_num",
 "real_position",
 "real_position_side",
 "join_date",
 "country"
)
```

Note that this could be defined outside of the method, for the sake of both efficiency and logic.

Inside the method, we make a map of all the `Stat` elements with `Type` attributes, and then filter the keys using our set:

```
  val stats: Map[String, String] = (n \\ "Stat").flatMap {
    s => s.attribute("Type").map(_.toString -> s.text)
  }.toMap.filterKeys(keys)
```

Now we have a map from the keys we're interested in to the text contents of the appropriate `Stat` elements. So if for example our `n` looks like this:

```
<Player uID="john">
  <Stat Type="first_name">John</Stat>
  <Stat Type="last_name">Doe</Stat>
  <Stat Type="some_irrelevant_thing">blah</Stat>
</Player>
```

Our result will be `Map(first_name -> John, last_name -> Doe)`, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
(for (
      s <- Seq("first_name",
        "last_name",
        "known_name",
        "birth_date",
        "weight",
        "height",
        "jersey_num",
        "real_position",
        "real_position_side",
        "join_date",
        "country");
      val Some(st) = (n \\ "Stat").filter(_.attribute("Type").filter(_.toString() == s).isDefined)
      if (st != "")
    ) yield (s -> st)).toMap
```

something like that

Comment: This will break if the filter returns `None`, use `st <- // filter` instead

Comment: It will not break but skip the value and take next one, this is desired behavior as far as I understood.

Comment: @jdevelop no, it will break with a match error. `val Some(st) = x`is a shorthand for `x match { case Some(st) => }`.

Comment: Just try `val x: Option[Int] = None; for(y <- List(""); val Some(st) = x) yield 2` and anyway `Option` is a monad, so why not use it like that?

Comment: There is no need for `isDefined`. Just use `st <- ...` instead.

Comment: completely true, but I remember that it is possible to pattern match on type constructors in for-loop somehow, can you please remind me with that?

Comment: You could do it like `... val st = x match { case ... }` but you would still have to add a guard to skip invalid values and that is neither clean, nor necessary. Afaik there is no way to safely match in a header of a for-comprehension.